# Keras predict new image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using [this example.](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/)

when run all as untouched all works fine, but now I want to make a test of a single file,
I'm doing it in this mode:

```
image = encode_img('new_image/x3fwf.png')
image = image['image']
image.shape 
// TensorShape([200, 50, 1])
prediction_model.predict(image)
```

so here i get back:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for
> '{{node functional_13/pool1/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT,
> data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1,
> 2, 2, 1]' with input shapes: [?,50,1,32].

I know I am doing something wrong, but not understand what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a dimension to it so that it can be called in a batch mode `([1,200,50,1])`

You can use for an array,

```
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```